# How do I find the size of a char array?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, sizeof

How should I go about finding the length of a char array in C++? I've tried two methods already, but they both have resulted in the wrong number of characters in the array. I've used `strlen` and the `sizeof` operator so far, to no avail.

```
void countOccurences(char *str, string word)
{
    char *p;
    string t = "true";
    string f = "false";

    vector<string> a;

    p = strtok(str, " ");
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        a.push_back(p);
        p = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    int c = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
    {
        if (word == a[i])
        {
            c++;
        }
    }

    int length = sizeof(str); //This is where I'm having the problem
    string result;
    cout << length << "\n";

    if (length % 2 != 0)
    {
        if (c % 2 == 0)
        {
            result = "False";
        }
        else
        {
            result = "True";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (c % 2 == 0)
        {
            result = "True";
        }
        else
        {
            result = "False";
        }
    }

    if (strlen(str) != 0)
    {
        cout << result;
    }
}

int boolean()
{
    char str[1000];
    cin.getline(str, sizeof(str));
    string word = "not";
    countOccurences(str, word);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: char array or C-string? There is a difference. If a C-string and `strlen()` isn't working, then you've screwed up already. If you lost the size of a regular array, then you've screwed up already.

Comment: @sweenish I'm talking about a char array.

Comment: `strtok` modifies the string. What value do you expect to get back? The size of the original string which no longer exists?

Comment: `std::size()` can tell you the size of an array *if it has not decayed to just a pointer*. Btw; why are you using a C-style array and not a `std::vector` or `std::array` in the first place?

Comment: What do you want to do in "countOccurences"?

Comment: @Bernd I'm trying to find the number of times "not" occurs in the char array and then compare that to the length of the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sizeof(str)` is wrong. It gives you the size of a pointer (`str` is a pointer), which is a fixed number, normally either `4` or `8` depending at your platform.

`std::strlen(str)` is correct, **but** `strtok` inserts a bunch of `\0` into your array *before* you try to obtain the size. `strlen` will stop at the first `\0`, and give you the number of characters preceeding it.

Call `strlen` before `strtok` and save its return value to a variable.

Comment: you are right - but using a c-style string/array is bad anyway. You should avoid that. Use just these functions: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline.
In addition you should not use strtok. Faster and safer is std::string_view.

Comment: @Bernd Is there a reason why using c-style string/arrays are bad in c++? I'm relatively new to the language and I haven't come across many issues with it so far.

Comment: Yes, because c-strings are just a pointer to some data. You loose the information where the string ends. This is handled in C string with a final "zero".
strtok is just there for C compatibility. The problem with this function is that it modifies the data. Okay you could copy it before tokenize...
But there are smarter solutions (If you like I can post something)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/v93e7c) you can find a modern c++ solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename String>
inline std::size_t StrLength(String&& str)
{
    using PureString = std::remove_reference_t<std::remove_const_t<String>>;
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<char, PureString>){
        return 1;
    }
    else 
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<char*, PureString>){
        return strlen(str);
    }
    else{
        return str.length();
    }
}

template<
    typename String,
    typename Lambda,
    typename Delim = char
>
void ForEachWord(String&& str, Lambda&& lambda, Delim&& delim = ' ')
{
    using PureStr = std::remove_reference_t<std::remove_reference_t<String>>;
    using View = std::basic_string_view<typename PureStr::value_type>;

    auto start = 0;
    auto view = View(str);

    while(true)
    {
        auto wordEndPos = view.find_first_of(delim, start);
        auto word =  view.substr(start, wordEndPos-start);

        if (word.length() > 0){
            lambda(word);
        }
        
        if (wordEndPos == PureStr::npos)
        {
            break;
        }
        start = wordEndPos + StrLength(delim);
    }
}

int main() {
   std::string text = "This is not a good sentence.";
   auto cnt = 0;
   ForEachWord(
       text, 
       [&](auto word)
       {
          //some code for every word... like counting or printing
          if (word == "not" ){
             ++cnt;
          }
       },
       ' '
   );
   std::cout << cnt << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The "end of a string" is the char '\0' check for that character to stop the search.